# [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1':

Tags: sql-server, yii, yii2

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax
>   near '@P1'. The SQL being executed was: call
>   sp_inX_Test('10105','Test')' in
>   C:\wamp64\www\Test\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Schema.php:633 Stack trace:

I am getting this issue when I try to call stored procedure with two parameters.

Here is my php code

```
$sql = "call sp_inX_Test(:route_code,:name)";
$params = [ ':route_code'=> Yii::$app->request->post('RouteCode'),':name'=> Yii::$app->request->post('Name')];
$command =  Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql,$params);
$areaPerformance = $command->queryAll();
```

I tried this , working only , but getting issue if the parameter has space inside.

```
   $command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("sp_inX_Test @RouteCode=".Yii::$app->request->post('RouteCode').",
    @Name=".Yii::$app->request->post('Name')."");
    $areaPerformance = $command->queryAll();
```

Next exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Foil'. The SQL being executed was:
>   sp_inX_Test @RouteCode=10103,         @Name=Aluminium Foil'
>   in C:\wamp64\www\Mahroos\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Schema.php:633

Comment: Use exec instead of call.

Comment: Never seen a sql server sproc executed using call before.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37988488/how-to-call-stored-procedure-with-parameters-in-yii2

Comment: i tried not working @Zhorov

Comment: Please give me syntax @TrevorBrooks

Comment: Ok please tell me the syntax @JacobH

Comment: I tried , Something is missing

Comment: @TrevorBrooks updated question please check

Comment: It's probably `... @Name='".Yii::$app->request->post('Name')."'" ` (missing `'` before and after the `Yii::$app->request->post('Name')` ), but please, use this **only** for this test and always use **parameterized queries**.